# Next.js - Dynamic routing for blog posts and search urls is being overlapped

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes

I have these pages on my Blog made in `Next.js`:

```
/blog
/blog/article
/blog/search?author=author-name
/blog/search?category=post-category
/blog/search?value=search-value
```

And 2 components: `Blog` (which I reuse in almost every page) and `BlogPost` (I use it only for the `/blog/article` route).

And the way I have the routing organized is like this:

```
---> blog
   --> index.js (this will render <Blog /> component 
   --> [slug].js (this will render <BlogPost /> component
```

Finally, I want that the rest of pages:

```
`/blog/search?author=author-name`
`/blog/search?category=post-category`
`/blog/search?value=search-value`
```

to be rendered in `index.js` since they also need to be rendered with the  component. But right now, the `[slug].js` is being rendered. Is there a way to make it happen? Do I need to change the way the `url` is structured?

Thanks!

Comment: So if i understand the question you want the page search to also return back to the index page or?

Comment: yes, thats the idea

Comment: Can you post up your slug code please then

Comment: You can setup a [`rewrites`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) rule to map `/blog/search` to `/blog`, e.g. `{ source: '/blog/search', destination: '/blog' }`.